# How to set radio button as true bydefault

Tags: jsf

I want to make my radio button bydefault as true. My sample code is given below:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{empcategoryBean.dto.is_Esi}"  disabled="#{empcategoryBean.sta}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="1"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="0"/>
        </p:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 0):

go the following link:-

[JSF set default value Radio Button h:selectOneRadio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893707/jsf-set-default-value-radio-button-hselectoneradio)

Set value in your backing bean with the desired default value. For example if you want "1" as default: